# Fscanf in exercise file from C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm studying for an examination of programming in C, and I'm thinking and solving exercises. In this concrete, I jump a mistake with the fscanf (terminal:"passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]...") and do not know how to fix it.
Thanks greetings

"Program that given a file data.txt whole numbers 1 line, read it all and visualize the minimum odd, a function should do this and return the minimum, the main program it displayed on screen"

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  FILE* fichero;

  int little(){
    //open the file
    char name[10] = "datos.txt";
    fichero = fopen( name,"r"); //opened in read mode
    int whatis,minimpar=99999999;
    while(!EOF){
      fscanf("%d",&whatis); //We took the number to the variable until we reach the end of file
      if (whatis%2==1){ //If the variable is odd
         if(whatis<minimpar){ //And is smaller than we have saved
            minimpar=queserasera; 
         }
      }
    }
    fclose(fichero); 
    return minimpar; //Return variable
  }

  int main(void){
    int a;
    a=little();
    printf("The smallest of the odd file is: %d",a);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `fichero` pass to `fscanf` as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

This `while(!EOF)` is always false, try `while (fscanf(fichero, "%d", &whatis) == 1)`, the reason is that `EOF` is a constant value that is returned by I/O functions to indicate that the current I/O operation failed because the file is at the end.

Also, `fscanf()` takes as the first paramter the file where you want to scan from, the way you have it causes undefined behavior, because the string literal will be treated as a `FILE *`.

You must enable compiler warnings specially because you are learning, compiler warining and error messages are a good source for learning in my opinion.